# Having multiple pander()s in a function

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, pander

How do I create multiple outputs via `pander()` in a knitted document "asis" ?

When I have multiple calls of `pander` in a function, only the most recent one is shown in the HTML output. Here's an example:

```
tmp = function() {
  pander('A')
  pander('B')
  pander('C')
}
tmp()
```

In the knitted document this gives: C

I could set `panderOptions('knitr.auto.asis', FALSE)` or I could use `cat()` so that the `pander()` output is written to the standard output. But then it's formatted as code, not as part of the document. As I need `pander()` to format a few tables for me, this does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tmp` function will return only the last object -- that's why only `C` is printed. If you want to write each object to the `stdout` right away without the auto-asis convenience option, then you have to both disable the option like you did *and* use the relate `knitr` chunk option, eg:

````
```{r results='asis'}
library(pander)
panderOptions('knitr.auto.asis', FALSE)
tmp = function() {
  pander('A')
  pander('B')
  pander('C')
}
tmp()
```
````

See more examples in the related ["Using pander with knitr" vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pander/vignettes/knitr.html).

Comment: Ah, great! the `results='asis'` option was what I was missing!